# Prism modules and multiple DI-containers

Tags: architecture, module, prism, ioc-container, prism-5

Our application has several windows. Currently they run in separete processes, but that makes communication between them awkward (and multiplies resources like JMS connections etc.). Idea was to refactor the structure towards single process to ease communication and resource/service sharing.

I though about using prism modules this way:

[image: prism modules]

The idea was to load each windows "main program" as a prism module and each module could then initialize its own DI container as it sees fit (each window is produced by different team). Modules would not be making contributions to each others UI, but they may share services through Main MEF container. Main can also load few general services that would be available to modules.

By separating each module to its own DI-container I try to prevent dependency hell between modules and encourage more disciplined usage of services from another module.

1. Is this even possible, or do DI containers collide with each other (being in the same process)?
2. Is there something in Prism that would fight agains this kind of solution?
3. Should I just create own mini-modulesystem instead of prisms IModule

Another possibility we have been investicating would be to put each module to its own AppDomain. That would however have its own drawbacks (like sharing services must be done through wcf etc). Separate AppDomains would however prenvent possible DI-container collisions and allow main to work as a watchdog in case of a failing AppDomain. Does anyone have experience with AppDomain based solution? Are there any issues that have not been described here?

Answer (score 0):

First, running views on separate processes is a bad idea.
Second,all the idea of prism is to run in 1 process and 1 (!) container that manage all views.
The communication between view is done with services and event aggregations.
You don't need any dependencies between them.
I will give you an example:
Your app represent a shop.
you will have 1 module that handle vegetables (views,view models,models)
you will have 1 module that handle dairy products (views,view models,models)
each module need to use soap service to get the data.
this will be a shared service that will be inject to both modules.
your first module need to tell everyone who cares that all vegetables are sold,
it will send an event (aggregation) and the module who need to know will listen to this kind of event.
and so on, all the communication between modules is done mostly with shared services and event aggregations.
hope I answered your question

Comment: Thanks. What you describe is the "normal" usage of prism. I intended to use it as a ad-hoc osgi for .net. Module was intended to be used as a larger concept than prism module normally is because it is its own solution and different modules are produced by different teams. I quess I'll try the appdomain based and custom mef-module based approaches.

Comment: I see what your are saying. I think you could achieve it without app domains .